# Onclick event listener not registering class

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
$(function () {
        $("#dataTable tbody tr").each(function () {
            var first = $(this).find("td:first").text();
            var second = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)");
            var ulId = '#' + second.find("ul:first").attr('id');

            $(ulId).tagit({
                placeholder: '',
                maxTags: 3,
                inputWidth: 1,
                tagsChanged: function () {
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: 'search.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    query: first
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data.length > 1) {
                        $(ulId).tagit("fill", data);
                        //$(".tagit-label").one('click', function() {
                        //    console.log($(this).html());
                        //});
                    } else {
                        second.html(data);
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        $(".tagit-label").one('click', function() {
            console.log($(this).html());
        });
    });
```

I want to do something after a clicking a div that has the class of `tagit-label`. The class is only created after the AJAX response has successfully returned an array consisting of more than 1 element. As click is an event listener shouldn't this not matter? If I have the click event in `success:` for the AJAX call it does whatever is inside the click code for the amount of times tags have been created. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: It should be `on()` not `one()`.

Comment: No it shouldn't - I was using `one` specifically to see if that would stop the loop (it didn't obviously)

Answer (score 0):

Put back your click event listener in `success:` and make Ajax call `method:'POST'`

It should work.

Thanks

Comment: Didn't change anything - still looped over several times.